# Its possible set maxmimum table row limit in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have simple application with MySQL database.

In database, I have table LOG:

```
ID | MESSAGE | Time
```

Is there any way, how to define max limit row for table?

I want store only 1000 last logs.

I am using MySQLWORKBENCH.

Comment: Do you simply throw away any loggable information when you get to 1000 rows or is there a deeper question here?

Comment: When I add log id 1001 I want remove log id 1, just remove.

Comment: You could update the code being used to write the data to the database to delete what's in the table before you write to it if `id % 1000` == 0.